# Two way SMS threads

Tags: php, twilio, sms, vonage

I am trying to write a threaded messaging application.

Users can be in multiple threads and send/receive messages using SMS (probably with Nexmo or Twilio).

How can I link an SMS reply to the original message? In e-mail we use a thread->id in the reply to.

Not sure if this is even possible.

Mick

Comment: With all the available free comms mechanisms you are going to use SMS which cost money to use?

Comment: Yes, because it meets our customers requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/conversations-api), each unique conversation between the same participant (thread) would need to have uniqueness from the phone number side, so you would set up a new proxy phone number if you have multiple threads with the same participant going on. This will also allow for threading on the end-users SMS client.

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck, I'm afraid, SMS itself does not support any additional information that can help with threading. With Nexmo (now rebranded to Vonage), you can set a `client-ref` that is included in the delivery receipt to help with understanding delivered messages, but there isn't a way to do threading with SMS.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to have group chats through SMS?

Not sure if that is what you are looking to do, but maybe this would work:

A thread would be a Nexmo (now Vonage) number that the users would send their messages to and your application would listen for inbound messages to that number and then redirect to the other users in the thread.

Here is a use case pretty much illustrating what I was describing above: https://developer.nexmo.com/use-cases/private-sms-communication

Is that similar to what you are looking to accomplish?